# How make logs apper in '* What went wrong:' and '* Try:' section of Gradle failed build output?

Tags: gradle

I know I can **throw an exception, to achive its message in 'what went wrong' section**, but it also stops execution, so I get informed only about one error at the time(in the 'what went wrong' section). There can me multiple error logs, if appears, thrown as exception message and get them all into the 'what went wrong' section, **but it is an ugly hack, and I cant get message into 'Try:' section** like this.

So generaly, should, and can I get my logs into  '* What went wrong:' and '* Try:' sections to make project specific build errors chasing easier? And if so, how?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only option is to throw an exception (commonly `GradleException`) with an appropriate message, which will be shown under "What went wrong:". To keep executing the build after an exception, run with `--continue`. This will aggregate all messages at the end. You can't influence the message in the "Try:" section.

Comment: I've just realized, that using exception is generally not the best solution. When I'm importing new project into IDE using gradle, and script(so whole import) fails on exception that some jar is missing(its pretty common, when importing new project I dont know what it needs - also jar Im depending on is not available publicly). I'd like to find some solution that gently tells: You also have to provide this and that...preferably somewhere on the end of output, instead of crashing project import and simmilar tasks using the script. Probably, the red error log is the only and the best solution :)

Comment: Not sure I can follow. Generally speaking, an IDE import will trigger configuration of the build, but not its execution. Are you considering to throw exceptions at configuration time? I was talking about throwing exceptions at execution time (e.g. from a task action).

Comment: I'm throwing and exception in dependencies{} section(not wraped in anything else) where I simply do something like this 'new File('lib/mylib.jar')', if not I throw GradleException. This exception occures during Gradle import proces(and stops it) in Intellij Idea 12.1.4 which I use. Maybe there is some Gradle way to realize if dependency is presented or not, which is not checked during the import, but if IDE tries to build app during import, there is no way to finish it successfully with thrown exception. Or, maybe Im not defining my app specific dependencies in proper place?